# Why can't I pass an rvalue std::stringstream by value to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue

Why does this code not compile?

```
#include <sstream>

void f(std::stringstream) { }

int main() {
    f(std::stringstream{});
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
         f(std::stringstream{});
                              ^
```

If I replace `std::stringstream` with another type that's noncopyable it works fine. Shouldn't this use `stringstream`'s move constructor?

Comment: With clang-500.2.79 and -std=c++11 on MacOS the code compiles.  Which compiler and standard library are you using?

Comment: Your standard library implementation is probably incomplete.

Comment: @razeh I'm using GCC 4.8.2 and clang 4.2.1 on debian testing, don't know how to tell what stdlib I'm using.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm using GCC 4.8.2 and clang 4.2.1 on debian testing with the stdlib that is bundled with it, seems like that should be up to date.

Comment: @uk4321: Perhaps it should be, but it is not.  Try a simple test: `std::stringstream s1; std::stringstream s2(std::move(s1));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing move constructor for `stringstream` is [a known missing feature](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316) in GCC's implementation of the C++ standard library. If I'm reading the comments on that report correctly, it is intentionally missing because it would rely on other changes, and those other changes would break the ABI, so the GCC folks have chosen to break the ABI only once (if possible), and that time has not yet come.