# sort a string word by word

Tags: c++, string

I was recently doing a problem on string and suddenly this thing came to my mind that, how could i arrange the words of string in increasing order of their ascii values.

***for example there's a string:***

```
ab nn ac mm
```

***so the output should be:***

```
ab ac mm nn
```

actually i want to arrange them according to sum of ascii values of each letter of a word.

**like in above example**

```
ab has a sum of (97+98)=195
ac has a sum of (97+99)=196
```

and so on...

I want to know is there any **efficient** method of doing it or is there any function in **STL** which i can use here?

to make the question more clear Here's a second example if a string is-

```
acd abz
```

then output is-
    acd abz 
as sum of ascii of each letter of "acd" is lesser than that of "abz"

```
acd sums to (97+99+100)=296
abz sums to (97+98+122)=317
```

Comment: What has your research revealed so far? What code have you written to attempt a solution?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit great point, I should also stop answering "why is this not working" kind of questions, but the temptation was too great :)

Comment: I was thinking about a brute force solution of traversing whole string and finding sum for each word and storing the sum and index of first letter of each word in a pair.But i never implemented this

Comment: The "sum of ASCII values" is not really clear. Are you saying `ac` should be equal to `ca` *and* to `bb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your custom comparison, this code should do it, using a custom comparison function object (functor), i.e. in this case an object that implements `bool operator(x,y)` for usage in `std::sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct str_comp
{
    bool operator()(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) const
    {
        return std::accumulate(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), 0) < 
               std::accumulate(std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs), 0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string input_str {"acd abz aaayyyyy zzzaaaaa"};
    std::stringstream ss {input_str};
    std::vector<std::string> v_str { std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ss}, {} };
    std::sort(std::begin(v_str), std::end(v_str), str_comp());
    for (const auto& elem : v_str)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

Or, with a lambda function like a boss:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string input_str {"acd abz aaayyyyy zzzaaaaa"};
    std::stringstream ss {input_str};
    std::vector<std::string> v_str { std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ss}, {} };
    std::sort(std::begin(v_str), std::end(v_str), 
        [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
        {
            return std::accumulate(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), 0) < 
               std::accumulate(std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs), 0);
        }
    ); // end std::sort
    for (const auto& elem : v_str)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how the sort function is working here?

Comment: @SurayansTiwari it is based on quicksort, see `std::sort` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort The `string` class implements the `operator<` for lexicographical comparing of two strings, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp,  then `std::sort` is just using strings as plain old data in comparing them. Divide et impera.

Comment: @SurayansTiwari, you can also specify your comparison criterion in `std::sort`, as a functor (function object), i.e. object that implements `bool operator()(const string& x, const string& y)` in case you are not satisfied with lexicographical comparison. In your case, you take two strings and return their ascii cumulative difference, shouldn't be too hard to do, can simply use a cast to `short` from `char` to get the ascii code.

Comment: but i don't want to sort lexicographically

Comment: @SurayansTiwari, implement your own comparison function/functor that takes 2 `std::string`s as parameters and return a `bool`, then use it in `std::sort`

Comment: @SurayansTiwari see the edit. Next time please try to post what you've tried so far and where did it fail.

Comment: okay i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and push_back in a vector and sort the vector in the following ways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

  vector<string>v;
  std::string s="ab nn ac mm";
  istringstream t(s);

  string ss;

  while(t>>ss){

    v.push_back(ss);
   }

  sort(v.begin(),v.end());

  for (auto i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i){
          cout<<*i<<endl;

      }   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this code uses common standard functions/algorithms and is (in my opinion) efficient.
The splitting is done by a stringstream as you can see.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "abz acd";
    std::vector<std::string> substrings{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ std::stringstream{ input } }, std::istream_iterator<std::string>{} };

    std::sort(std::begin(substrings), std::end(substrings),
        [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) -> bool 
        { 
            auto calcAscii = [](const std::string& str) -> int 
            {   
                int ascii = 0;
                for (auto const& it : str)
                {
                    ascii += static_cast<int>(it);
                }

                return ascii;
            };

            return calcAscii(a) < calcAscii(b); 
        });

    std::string result;

    for (auto const& it : substrings)
    {
        result += it + " ";
    }

    std::cout << result;
}
```

Comment: nice point, trick that I learned: can use just `{}` instead of `std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}`, as template type deduction does it from you ;)

Comment: OP doesn't want lexicographical sorting - he wants to sort by sum of ascii code

Comment: @LMF, the line `std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ std::stringstream{ input } }...` won't compile, it looks like one cannot pass `std::stringstream` as a `rvalue`. I had to initialize it separately as `std::stringstream ss{ input };`, then use it as `std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ss}...` At least in g++, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20590449/3093378

Comment: @ikh LMF's example should provide MORE than enough hints how to do it in general.

Comment: @LMF, also `#include <iterator>` for `std::istream_iterator`

Comment: @LMF, I realized I had the same issue long time ago with temporary stringstreams, see 0x499602D2's answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/23714445/3093378 for a neat solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume your string has only *one* space, between a word and a word. Also I assume your string is trimed, which means it doesn't have any space in the head and tail of string. Let me show the code.

```
std::string sort_by_word_code(const std::string &src)
{
    if (src.empty())
        return "";

    typedef std::string::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef std::tuple<const_iterator, const_iterator, int> WordTuple;
    std::vector<WordTuple> words;

    const_iterator i = src.begin(), j;
    int code;

    while (1)
    {
        code = 0;
        for (j = i; j != src.end() && *j != ' '; ++j)
        {
            code += *j;
        }

        words.push_back(WordTuple(i, j, code));

        if (j == src.end())
            break;

        i = j + 1;
    }

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [](const WordTuple &t1, const WordTuple &t2) { return std::get<2>(t1) < std::get<2>(t2); }
        );

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(src.size());

    for (auto it = words.begin(); ; )
    {
        result.insert(result.end(),
            std::get<0>(*it),
            std::get<1>(*it)
            );

        ++it;
        if (it == words.end())
            break;

        result.push_back(' ');
    }

    return result;
}
```

[(live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20068435c82efd04)

The idea is simple. Create a vector which has the sum of ascii and begin/end of each word, sort it, and create a result string from it.